# Get file creation date in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the creation date of a file in Firebase Storage bucket. I tried getTimeCreated() but I am getting an error telling me that the function is undefined

```
bucket
    .listAll()
    .then((res) => {
      const promises = [];
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        const childrRef = storage.ref().child("test/" + folderRef.name);
        const imageRef = childrRef.child("profile.jpeg");

        promises.push(
          imageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url)
            console.log(childrRef.getTimeCreated())
            console.log(imageRef.getTimeCreated();
      }
```